# Indicator variables in a Linear regression

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, indicator-function

For linear regression analysis, will changing the indicator variables
change the table of sums of squares? Is there a way to illustrate this through a mathematical way via statistical formula or equations.

Comment: What kinds of "changes" are you making to indicator variables?

Comment: That's definitely one part i'm stuck at. On one hand, from what i've read, if you change coding scheme of the dummy variables, it can change sum of squares residual and regression. So if I conclude correctly, if no drastic change is made to indicator variables, then it will not affect SS.

Comment: Indicator variables should be zero or one, and you should have as many as you need to discriminate whatever is you are looking for.